# R bayesian moderator analysis

Tags: r, bayesian

I am making the transition from using frequentist methods for meta-analysis to a mixture of frequentist and bayesian, as needed. A barrier I am noticing is a lack of moderator analysis options in current packages for R.

the "bmeta" package appears to have the opportunity for moderator analysis but the interface and output are less than desirable. the "bayesmeta" package is more my speed and reminds me of "metafor" but it does not appear to have capacity for moderator analysis. It does provide far more diagnostic and posterior model checking that "bmeta" does nto seem to have.

Is this correct? Does anyone have suggestions or examples of how to go about this from a bayesian framework? Admittedly, I feel spoiled by "metafor" at the moment.